# Extending Sencha Touch Text Field

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.2

I am trying to extend the TextField to initialize the value based on the location information. The following code does what i need.

```
Ext.define("Tasks.view.LatitudeField", {
    extend: 'Ext.field.Text',
    alias:'widget.latitudeField',

    xtype: 'latitudefield',  

    initialize : function() 
    {
        console.log("Component Initialized ");
        this.setValue("123456");
    },
});
```

But when the field is displayed, I can't click on the x icon to clear the text. The x icon is not clickable at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the parent method in your initialize method:

```
initialize: function() {
    console.log("Component Initialized ");
    this.setValue("123456");

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```